# How to select all XML element

Tags: xml, xmp

How to I select all element in stRef:filePat in an XML file? The example I managed to find only select 1 particular element. 
eg:

```
/Volumes/WIP/AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/123.tif  
/Volumes/WIP/AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/456.tif  
/Volumes/WIP/AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/789.tif  
/Volumes//WIP/AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/321.tif
```

code

```
<xmpMM:Manifest>
  <rdf:Seq>
    <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <stMfs:linkForm>EmbedByReference</stMfs:linkForm>
      <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
        <stRef:filePath>/Volumes/WIP/AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/123.tif</stRef:filePath>
      </stMfs:reference>
    </rdf:li>
    <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <stMfs:linkForm>EmbedByReference</stMfs:linkForm>
      <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
        <stRef:filePath>/Volumes/WIP/AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/456.tif</stRef:filePath>
      </stMfs:reference>
    </rdf:li>
    <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <stMfs:linkForm>EmbedByReference</stMfs:linkForm>
      <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
        <stRef:filePath>/Volumes/WIP/AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/789.tif</stRef:filePath>
      </stMfs:reference>
    </rdf:li>
    <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <stMfs:linkForm>EmbedByReference</stMfs:linkForm>
      <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
        <stRef:filePath>/Volumes//WIP/AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/321.tif</stRef:filePath>
      </stMfs:reference>
    </rdf:li>
  </rdf:Seq>
</xmpMM:Manifest>
```

Comment: The answer will depend on the context. How and where are you trying to select the elements? Which tools are you using? What is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

using xpath request is : `//stRef:filePath`

Comment: You'll have to add a bit more information, so that the answer makes sense. XPath could be a way to go, yes, but the answer lacks a lot of information on how to use it and why it may work.

Comment: I know but the question lacks of informations and I can't comment on question yet :) If jeno could gives us more informations on the environment